# Unable to load Java class that consist robotframework keywords while it is trying to utilize method of another class via Object of that class

Tags: robotframework, jython-2.7

I have Class B which has Robotframework keyword and also calls method from Class A through 
object. I am getting 'NoClassDefFoundError' for Class A when trying to use keyword of Class B.  But, If I remove usage of class A in class B, I am able to use keywords of Class B. Below are my code:

```
Scenario 1: Error triggered
public class A{
public void method1(){
      System.out.println("This is method1")
}
}

public class B{
public void myRobotKeyword(){
A obj = new A();
obj.method1();
System.out.println("This is my kwyword");
}
}

Scenario 2: Successful retrieval of keyword in my test

public class B{

public void myRobotKeyword(){
 System.out.println("This is my keyword");
}
}
```

Comment: Is the second class part of your class path?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added the second class as part of class path in red.xml. But, it did not work.  Then, I tried to export both the classes in single jar file and it worked.